# Finding the largest size of 100 structs at compile time in C

Tags: c, algorithm, macros, preprocessor

I have 100 structs that look something like this:

```
struct s00 { char   data[30]; };
struct s01 { char   data[30]; };
struct s02 { int    data[10]; };
struct s03 { double data[5];  };
struct s04 { float  data[20]; };
struct s05 { short  data[15]; };
struct s06 { char   data[7];  };
struct s07 { int    data[19]; };
struct s08 { double data[11]; };
struct s09 { float  data[5];  };
struct s10 { char   data[52]; };
//...
struct s99 { char   data[12]; };

typedef struct s00 s00;
typedef struct s01 s01;
typedef struct s02 s02;
//...
typedef struct s99 s99;
```

I want to find the largest `sizeof` from among these structs at compile time. I tried using a comparison macro like this:

```
 #define LARGER(a, b) ((a) > (b) ? (a) : (b))
```

and then use that to construct the final define which will contain the result:

```
#define MAX_SIZEOF (LARGER(sizeof(s00), \
                    LARGER(sizeof(s01), \
                    LARGER(sizeof(s02), \
                    LARGER(sizeof(s03), \
                    LARGER(sizeof(s04), \
                    LARGER(sizeof(s05), \
                    LARGER(sizeof(s06), \
                    LARGER(sizeof(s07), \
                    LARGER(sizeof(s08), \
                    LARGER(sizeof(s09), \
                    LARGER(sizeof(s10), \
                    //...
                    sizeof(s99))) /*...*/ ))
```

However, the compiler runs out of space:

> Error C1060   compiler is out of heap space

Which makes sense, given that this `#define` has to keep track of alot of numbers, since it simply replaces text. To be specific, the number of integers found in `MAX_SIZEOF` is exponential and can be described as:

[image: number of numbers]

where x is equal the number of structs involved. Assuming 4 bytes for an integer, the compiler would need to allocate 30.4 sextillion terabytes to compute this macro (if my calculations are correct). The maximum my system could handle was 17 structs (786430 numbers, 3.14 megabytes).

I am not sure how I can find an efficient solution in C.

In C++ I could achieve this with `constexpr` quite easily without any compiling issues whatsoever:

```
constexpr size_t LARGER(size_t a, size_t b) {
    return a > b ? a : b;
}
constexpr size_t MAX_SIZEOF() {
return 
    LARGER(sizeof(s00), \
    LARGER(sizeof(s01), \
    LARGER(sizeof(s02), \
    LARGER(sizeof(s03), \
    LARGER(sizeof(s04), \
    LARGER(sizeof(s05), \
    LARGER(sizeof(s06), \
    LARGER(sizeof(s07), \
    LARGER(sizeof(s08), \
    LARGER(sizeof(s09), \
    LARGER(sizeof(s10), \
    //...
    sizeof(s99))/*...*/)));
```

But yeah, I have to use C only here. ...Thanks for any ideas!

Comment: Why would you want to do this?

Comment: @Edition i am sending a lot of different structs via sockets (CSFML UDP sockets). Since these sockets receive with a fixed size buffer, I want to find the maximum so that the buffer doesn't go out of bounds. I avoided this problem by simply allocating the buffer dynamically, but I'm at the point where I want to improve the perfomance of the program.

Comment: How can `c++` implement `constexpr` which evaluates what you tries here in `c` at compile time without screaming anything?

Comment: @user2162550 well I suppose the compiler really is evaluating each ternary operator instead of just replacing text while working through the layers.

Comment: or rather; the preprocessor is evaluating it.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can declare a union of all structs

```
union allstructs {
    struct s00 s00val;
    struct s01 s01val;
    /* ... */
    struct s99 s99val;
}
```

and get the size of the union

```
sizeof(union allstructs)
```

When you want to transmit structures over the network you should also think about packing/padding of structures, byte order and floating point implementation.

Comment: I was going for kind of  `max()` macro statements but this is much more nicer .... so +1

Comment: @Spektre I'd still be curious to see how that'd work

Comment: @StackDanny I added that approach as answer

Answer (score 1):

As I mentioned the other answer is way much nicer but as requested this works for me (on AtmelStudio 6.2 C compiler mode):

```cpp
typedef struct { char   data[30]; }s00;
typedef struct { char   data[30]; }s01;
typedef struct { int    data[10]; }s02;
typedef struct { double data[5];  }s03;
typedef struct { float  data[20]; }s04;
typedef struct { short  data[15]; }s05;
typedef struct { char   data[7];  }s06;
typedef struct { int    data[19]; }s07;
typedef struct { double data[11]; }s08;
typedef struct { float  data[5];  }s09;
typedef struct { char   data[5]; }s10;
typedef struct { char   data[5]; }s11;
typedef struct { char   data[5]; }s12;
typedef struct { char   data[5]; }s13;
typedef struct { char   data[5]; }s14;
typedef struct { char   data[5]; }s15;
typedef struct { char   data[2]; }s16;
typedef struct { char   data[5]; }s17;
typedef struct { char   data[5]; }s18;
typedef struct { char   data[5]; }s19;
typedef struct { char   data[3]; }s20;
typedef struct { char   data[5]; }s21;
typedef struct { char   data[5]; }s22;
typedef struct { char   data[5]; }s23;
typedef struct { char   data[5]; }s24;
typedef struct { char   data[5]; }s25;
typedef struct { char   data[5]; }s26;
typedef struct { char   data[4]; }s27;
typedef struct { char   data[5]; }s28;
typedef struct { char   data[5]; }s29;
typedef struct { char   data[5]; }s30;
typedef struct { char   data[5]; }s31;
typedef struct { char   data[5]; }s32;
typedef struct { char   data[5]; }s33;
typedef struct { char   data[5]; }s34;
typedef struct { char   data[5]; }s35;
typedef struct { char   data[5]; }s36;
typedef struct { char   data[5]; }s37;
typedef struct { char   data[5]; }s38;
typedef struct { char   data[99];}s39;

#define sm(a0,a1) (sizeof(a0)>sizeof(a1)?sizeof(a0):sizeof(a1))
#define mm(a0,a1) (a0>a1?a0:a1)
#define s_10 sm(sm(sm(sm(sm(sm(sm(sm(sm(s00,s01),s02),s03),s04),s05),s06),s07),s08),s09)
#define s_20 sm(sm(sm(sm(sm(sm(sm(sm(sm(s10,s11),s12),s13),s14),s15),s16),s17),s18),s19)
#define s_30 sm(sm(sm(sm(sm(sm(sm(sm(sm(s20,s21),s22),s23),s24),s25),s26),s27),s28),s29)
#define s_40 sm(sm(sm(sm(sm(sm(sm(sm(sm(s30,s31),s32),s33),s34),s35),s36),s37),s38),s39)
const int s_size=mm(mm(mm(s_10,s_20),s_30),s_40);
```

The single line version is not working but if I divide the value into multiple lines `(s_10,s_20,...)` then I can use even 40 `struct`s with correct output `99`. Have not tried more as I am too lazy to copy paste others... I do not think its allocation problem you got there more like the max limit per line length of the preprocessor ...

The output value is `s_size` and can be also a `#define` ...

Comment: Thanks for submitting! and yes, splitting it up is a nice idea~